# Google Maps iOS SDK 1.6 makes it blink

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I just updated my Google Maps iOS SDK **from 1.5 to 1.6** and now my markers are blinking.

Here's what I'm doing :

1. I have a list of 1200 markers
2. I'm catching movements on my map using *idleAtCameraPosition*
3. I'm getting the current displayed region and generating a list of a few markers to display in this area
4. I'm then using *[map clear]* to clear all the previously shown markers
5. Then I'm adding to my map all the markers to display

This used to work perfectly, but now for a reason I don't get **it blinks**. I think it has something to do with *[map clear]*.

What I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: I won't use map clear, because depending on the device you'll see the markers blinking. I will try to have a Dictionary to know which markers you have to remove and them put their map to nil (marker.map=nil) in order to remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got solved with the 1.6.1 update.